# Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS on Hyper-V 2012

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v, ubuntu-12.04, windows-server-2012

I have the following scenario:
Hyper-V 2012 server core installation.  On top of this i created a virtual machine on which i tried installing Ubuntu Server 12.04 which should not have any compatibility issues according to what Microsoft and Ubuntu are saying (although it is not officially supported).

I start, run the installation and everything is ok, no problems detecting the network device or the hard drive (unlike debian which didn't even detect the hard drive).

Once the installation is complete it asks me to reboot, it unmounts the "dvd drive" and reboots.  Once it tries to start again i get the following error:

Boot failure. Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in the selected Boot device.  It seems to not be booting up from the virtual hard drive.

The hard drive is set up in SCSI mode, nothing mounted on the IDE controller (no iso image or anything else.

Does anyone have any ideas on what i can do to solve this?

Comment: It appears that Hyper-V can not boot from SCSI drives, only from IDE devices, which to avoid the long explanation, are not as fast/efficient in real life as SCSI drives.  Same applies for the guest OS and how it utilizes the storage device.  Does the same apply for the virtual IDE interface?

Comment: Is your Ubuntu Server 12.04 installation media/iso is connected/mounted on scsi?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HYPER-V VMs only boot from the virtual IDE controller, not from the virtual SCSI controller.  When you have paravirtualized drivers installed, there is no difference in performance between the virtual IDE and SCSI controllers.  They both go through the paravirtualized path.